# install glib-2.52 on centos 6 from source

Tags: centos6, glib

i want instal glib.2.52.0 on centos 6 64
in ./configure no error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaBNi.png)
 in make step has error :

```
        CC       libglib_2_0_la-gqueue.lo
    CC       libglib_2_0_la-grand.lo
    CC       libglib_2_0_la-gregex.lo
    gregex.c: In function ‘g_regex_get_max_lookbehind’:
    gregex.c:1573:18: error: ‘PCRE_INFO_MAXLOOKBEHIND’ undeclared (first use in this function)
                  PCRE_INFO_MAXLOOKBEHIND, &max_lookbehind);
                  ^
    gregex.c:1573:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    make[4]: *** [libglib_2_0_la-gr[enter image description here][2]egex.lo] Error 1
```

i have
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)
g++ (GCC) 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)

please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning comes from PCRE; it seems you have an older version of PCRE installed; sadly, PCRE tends to change its API without notice.

You can build GLib with an internal copy of PCRE to avoid this issue, by passing the `--with-pcre=internal` argument to the `configure` script.